# ASP.Net Web API User Management

Tags: asp.net, e-commerce, identity

This is perhaps a broad question and I am not sure if it qualifies to be on stackoverflow.
In an ecommerce system, we have customers and backend administrators. Both of these types are logically the users. Should they be kept in the same Asp.Net user table, distinguished by roles, or some other approach should be considered?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend keeping all users in one table, and then having different roles associated with those users.

That makes more sense to me than having multiple tables for different users - for example, you'd need to add a new table when a new type of user is introduced.

Answer (score 0):

Number 1 to consider when thinking about storage is:
- is the shape of the data close enough to be stored together?
- can I distinguish the 2 types unequivocally when querying?
If the answer is yes, then store it together, if not, separately